# Apache httpd hangs on a single long running request

Tags: apache-2.2

In Apache httpd 2.2.15 I'm seeing all new requests hang following a single long running request- as though httpd were a single blocked thread. This is behaving the same way with prefork, worker, and event MPMs.

The long running request is a PHP application - I've tried all MPM's both with and without fast cgi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with the session:

http://php.net/session_write_close

> Session data is usually stored after your script terminated without
>   the need to call session_write_close(), but as session data is locked
>   to prevent concurrent writes only one script may operate on a session
>   at any time.

I simply wrapped the long-running bit with `session_write_close()` and `session_start()`